# how to get difference between window height and scroll location?

Tags: javascript, typescript, window, infinite-scroll, angular10

I want to  make custom infinite scroll, so  when I try  this

```
 const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
if(window.innerHeight-scrollPosition >100){
console.log("end")
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your wanting to know when your 100 pixels away from the end, then you can get the current element scrollHeight and subtract the parent elements height and then subtract your extra 100.

Now compare this to the parentElements scrollTop, if it's greater then your scrollbar is within this 100px section..

Example below.. If you scroll down until your within 100 pixels of the end, the background will change silver.

```js
document.body.innerText =
  new Array(400).fill('Scroll me down, ').join('');

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  const body = document.body;
  const parent = body.parentElement;
  const pixelsFromBottom = 
    body.scrollHeight -
    parent.clientHeight
    -100;
  body.classList.toggle('inf'
    ,parent.scrollTop > pixelsFromBottom);
});
```

```css
.inf {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

This will work not with just Body, but also any sub controls too, below I've created a header footer, with and a scrollable region.

```js
const scroller = document.querySelector('main');
const target = document.querySelector('.content');

target.innerText =
  new Array(400).fill('Scroll me down, ').join('');

scroller.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  const body = target;
  const parent = body.parentElement;   
  const pixelsFromBottom = 
    body.scrollHeight -
    parent.clientHeight
    -100;
  parent.classList.toggle('inf'
    ,parent.scrollTop > pixelsFromBottom);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  flex: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.inf {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<header>This is a header</header>
<main><div class="content">main</div></main>
<footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

Comment: @JohnDoe I've added an example using a fixed header & footer.